# Best way to set up a 4x4 grid of buttons in swift 3

Tags: swift, button, grid

This is my first time working in and with xCode. I am coding a drum pad but am struggling with the User Interface.

Right now i have two views each containing a 4x4 button grid. The first one is for "triggering" the audio samples once a button is pressed. The second one contains a set of toggle buttons used to control a step sequencer.

The app itself is working fine. But im not sure how to build the interface in 'good fashion' So far I have used Interface Builder to create the grid.. set up the constrains manually so that the pads adapt to the device width, and stretch evenly across the screen.

The thing that makes me insecure is how laggy the interface builder runs since i have created these constrains.. might this also affect App performance and launch time?

So i looked up ways to create the grid programmaticaly and came across `UICollectionView`with its reusable cells it seems to fit my use case.. but it also seems a bit like overdoing it.

Its for  school, due date is coming closer and somehow i am stuck since days at this point. So could someone please point me in the right direction... how would a modern ios developer set up this grid.

thank you very much

Comment: The answer below using UIStackViews is a good one. So is using a UICollectionView. Both controls were created by Apple to reduce the amount of constraints you need to create. I'm a bit more concerned with your comment about IB being "laggy". The obvious first question is... how does that actual app perform? In some cases it may perform a bit laggy in the simulator but ok on a real device (particularly if the app utilizes the GPU in a device). A second question... is Xcode the issue? How old is the Mac? What version of macOS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Stack View** for the solving of this issue.It could be filled by buttons programmatically or just from storyboard.

This is example form the `storyboard`.

[image]

And this how it is looks at the emulator.

[image]

Comment: Im on it. Thank you, Oleg.

Comment: How do I do this programmatically?